# Formulario Django ImageField editar checkbox de borrado

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, checkbox

Estoy en un formulario de Django y quiero modificar la casilla automática que sale en un campo ImageField.

El problema es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La casilla para limpiar la imagen guardada aparece en una línea superior, y lo que quiero es que aparezca justo al lado de la palabra Limpiar.
Alguien sabe como poder modificar esto?

Espero ayuda, muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Me da la sensación de que es porque no tiene espacio para ponerlo junto, ¿si usas el zoom del navegador te sigue haciendo lo mismo? De todos modos, ¿podrías mostrar esa parte del template?